# How to properly display translated strings defined in a dictionary in both section titles and bookmarks?

Tags: hyperref, languages, bookmarks, dictionaries

From section titles and bookmarks point of view, translated strings from `translator` package behave differently, depending if they are defined directly within the `.tex` file or in a dictionary: in the latter case, both section title and bookmark just display the key of the translated string instead of the translation.

### Case *okay both* in section title and in bookmark

In the following MCE, a translated string *directly defined* within the `.tex` file is used in a section title *via the `\translatelet` macro*:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\deftranslation[to=English]{key-from-document}{translation from document}
%
\translatelet\MacroFromDocument{key-from-document}
%
\begin{document}
\section{\MacroFromDocument}
Indirect (macro) use of \verb|\translate| (from document).
\end{document}
```

This case is

- okay in section title,
- okay in bookmark,

as the translation "translation from document" appears in both of them

### Case *okay* in section title but *not okay* in bookmark

In the following MCE, a translated string *directly defined* within the `.tex` file is used in a section title *directly with* `\translate`:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\deftranslation[to=English]{key-from-document}{translation from document}
%
\begin{document}
\section{\translate{key-from-document}}
Direct use of \verb|\translate| (from document).
\end{document}
```

This case is:

- okay in section title: the translation "translation from document" appears in it,
- *not* okay in bookmark: the translation is replaced by the key "key-from-document".

### Case *not okay* both in section title and in bookmark

In the following MCE, a translated string *defined in a dictionary* is used in a section title *via the `\translatelet` macro* and *directly with* `\translate`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mydictionary.dict}
\ProvidesDictionary{mydictionary}{English}
\deftranslation{key-from-dictionary}{translation from dictionary}
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\deftranslation[to=English]{key-from-document}{translation from document}
\translatelet\MacroFromDictionary{key-from-dictionary}
%
\begin{document}
\section{\MacroFromDictionary}
Indirect (macro) use of \verb|\translate| (from dictionary).
\section{\translate{key-from-dictionary}}
Direct use of \verb|\translate| (from dictionary).
\end{document}
```

This case is:

- *not* okay in section titles: the translation is replaced by the key "key-from-document",
- *not* okay in bookmarks: the translation is replaced by the key "key-from-document".

All the wrong cases are related to the hyperref warning: "Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): [...] removing `\translate ' on input line [...]" but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: An expandable alternative: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/translations the CTAN description is a bit misleading, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following appears to work. I have

1. renamed the dictionary to `mydictionary-English`
2. added `\usedictionary {mydictionary}` to the preamble

Code for your last case:

*edit*: apologies I just checked for the section headings, not the bookmarks; the bookmarks are yet another problem. The indirect use is ok, but the direct use of the (protected) `\translate` macro is not to `hyperref`'s liking.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{translator}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mydictionary-English.dict}
\ProvidesDictionary{mydictionary}{English}
\deftranslation{key-from-dictionary}{translation from dictionary}
\end{filecontents*}
\usedictionary {mydictionary}


\begin{document}

\translatelet\MacroFromDictionary{key-from-dictionary}

\section{\MacroFromDictionary}
Indirect (macro) use of \verb|\translate| (from dictionary).

\section{\translate{key-from-dictionary}}
Direct use of \verb|\translate| (from dictionary).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Anyway, your answer helped me a lot as it pointed out that, with a dictionary (sorry for the misuse of it), the indirect use is okay as long as the `\translatelet` macro is defined within the document body (and _not_ in preamble).

Comment: I just come back from reading the doc of `translator` and it says the package loads the dictionaries at begin document. This might explain why `\translatelet` should be used in the body. Apart from that, as the `\translate` command is unexpandable, I see no easy way apart precisely what you call the `indirect way` with `\translatelet` to get your bookmarks right.

Comment: The fact that `\translate` is unexpandable is the main reason why I wrote the `translations` package (as part of the `exsheets` bundle)...